# How to Integrate Google+ API iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication, google-api, google-plus

I am working on an  iPhone application in which i have to implement Google+ API for login and fetching user details.I have used the API for it from this link https://developers.google.com done everything but immediately after login I  am  getting  an error invalid scope.I don't know what i am missing out.Please let me know how to acheive this.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the relative code and error logs? This will give us something to go on.

Answer (score 0):

To access certain stuff on behalf of the user, we need to tell google that we are looking for such information (Access calendars, google+ etc).

The way to tell this to google is by defining scope. For google plus use

```
@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"
```

Refer to the SDK where to pass in the scope. Also make sure that you enable Google Plus in the `Google API Console`.

Comment: I have integated the Google Plus SDK in my project but it is giving me the error Unknown class GooglePlusSignInButton in Interface Builder file.and crashing the application. Thanks